# Stored Procedure Error

Tags: mysql, join, stored-procedures

I am  creating  Stored Procedure but get an error.

My Stored Procedure:

```
Create Procedure Join()
BEGIN
SELECT Orders.orderId, Customers.customerName, Orders.orderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerId=Customers.CustomerId;
END
```

Error Is Below:

Error

> SQL query: Documentation
>
> Create Procedure Join() BEGIN SELECT Orders.orderId,
>   Customers.customerName, Orders.orderDate FROM Orders INNER JOIN
>   Customers ON Orders.CustomerId=Customers.CustomerId; END MySQL said:
>   Documentation
>
> 1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'Join() BEGIN SELECT Orders.orderId, Customers.customerName, Orders.orderDate ' Ã  la ligne
>   1

Comment: `Join` could be a reserved word, try changing that

Comment: Thanks For help it's procedure Name give error I change that and problem solve Thanks again guys

Comment: Join is reserved word, rename Join to smething else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Procedure User()
BEGIN
SELECT Orders.orderId, Customers.customerName, Orders.orderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerId=Customers.CustomerId;
END

Answer (score 0):

Try Join() in place of `Join`().